# mcntl_fork() vs system('program.php 1 2 3 4 &')

Tags: php, mysql, fork

I run into some problem and I am wondering what would be the best practice?

I have a parent program, which permanently checks a DB for a queue. When there is something in the queue, it forks a child and does multiple updates on the DB, until the end conditions are met and the child exits. That closes the MySQL connection for all other children. I can do a check on each child update query and open it again, but this risks, that in the milliseconds between opening and query another child closes the connection again.

I think it would be better to start 'a child' as a separate program start with `system('child.php')`. This child.php would have the routines separately programmed.

Would that make sense? The problem with this, I haven't found exactly the command for `system("child.php $arg1 $arg2 $arg4 $arg5 $arg6 &")`.

What would be the best practice and for the system call, what is the exact format?

To give you a scale of things. I would need to run 10k - 20k processes.

Comment: Since you ended up with more than a few processes and went to 10-20k, that's a clear indication you're doing something wrong and this is 99% an XY problem. If you fork, establish db connection in the child. I'm surprised you were even able to share the db connection without broken pipe message. How come you aren't using a dedicated process that runs forever and accepts input, then reacts to it? It'd be 1 process versus 20k processes, which is so much easier on the OS and hardware.

Comment: What about something like rabbitmq that may trigger your program to get the first entry of the queue?

Comment: @N.B. There is a misunderstanding. I need to run that many processes. The logic works and I want to know the best practice for this.

Comment: @Sixtus thanks for answering. I am not sending messages, I am making mathematical calculations in certain intervals and each interval will write back to the dB the result, which will be picked up by other programs.

Comment: Having slept over this, I think I may open a new connection inside the fork routine, which should then be closed when the child ‘exit()’?